# How to make all unit tests fail

Tags: java, unit-testing

I would like to find unit tests (written with JUnit) which never fail. I.e. tests which have something like

```
try {
// call some methods, but no assertions
} catch(Throwable e) {
// do nothing
}
```

Those tests are basically useless, because they will never find a problem in the code. So is there a way to make each (valid) unit test fail? For instance each call to any assert method would throw an exception? Then tests which still remain green are useless.

Comment: I can only think of doing a search and replace in your test directory. Perhaps when you find thme then put Assert.fail(..) in the catch. Sounds like a fundamentally bad test design though

Comment: @Jagger - I think the OP has the same opinion, but is dealing with a codebase where people did that (perhaps because they were required to have 100% test coverage metrics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one approach is to use something like [Jester](http://jester.sourceforge.net/) which implements [mutation testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing). It doesn't do things quite the way you've suggested, but it tries to find tests which will still pass however much you change the production code, but randomly mutating it and rerunning the tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make *every* call to *every* `Assert` method fail, then I'm not certain how to help you.  @JonSkeet's suggestion of Jester may be close to what you want.

However, if you're trying to find *an* `Assert` method that always fails, [`Assert.fail`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#fail%28java.lang.String%29) is what you want.  It throws an `AssertionError` on invokation.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't think this is really what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah I find it somewhat unclear what exactly the OP wants.  It seems that your suggestion *might* be a little closer. But this is definitely the answer to the question "For instance each call to any assert method would throw an exception?".

Comment: In what way is it an answer to that? How does it answer the question of how to make (say) `Assert.areEqual` always fail?

Comment: The OP wants all `Assert.assertX` methods to throw `AssertionError` irrespective of the arguments passed.

Comment: @JonSkeet Aaaah, I read that "each call to *some* assert method..." not "each call to *every* assert method..."  The word "any" is somewhat ambiguous, but I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to track code that swallows assertions, and/or does not make any assertions. The simplest way to do this will be to build your own JUnit JAR, replacing the original `Assert` class with your own.

This won't help you find cases where the assertions are bogus, and if you're in an environment where developers don't bother to assert, you're likely to have bogus assertions as well. It also doesn't help you find tests that are marked with `@Ignore`, but *grep* will do that for you.

Comment: "I'm assuming that you want to track code that swallows assertions, and/or does not make any assertions". Yes, that's exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for advises I'll take a look at Jester first and then perhaps try approach with creating my own Assert class. And some background inforation - we have quite old system (developed for ~10 years) with lot of legacy code and lot of old unit tests. That's why I am trying to find an automated way to find bad tests and also add such check to CI to detect same bad style in new tests.

Answer (score 0):

Add this as your default test implementation:

```
Assert.assertTrue(false);
```

Every test that starts this way will fail until you replace that line with something suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want but I understand that the Units are already written, so the only way I can imagine is to override the asserts methods, but even with this you will have to change a little bit the unit code.

Answer (score 0):

Run [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net) against your JUnit sources with the following configuration:

```
<module name="IllegalCatch">
    <property name="illegalClassNames" value="java.lang.Throwable, java.lang.Error, java.lang.AssertionError"/>
</module>
```